# WebClient authentication difference between .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, https, authorization, .net-2.0, webclient

I have a simple webclient call and I have to use .NET Framework 2.0 and HTTPS.
Working on a Windows 7 client and calling an IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012 with Windows authentication enabled.

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    wb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    NameValueCollection data = GeneratePostData();
    var res = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
    string strResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(res);
}
```

The difference in Fiddler between working capture and only 401 responses is the added **Seal (confidentiality)** in the not woking 2.0 version:

```
Unicode supported in security buffer.
OEM strings supported in security buffer.
Request server's authentication realm included in Type2 reply.
Sign (integrity)
Seal (confidentiality)
NTLM authentication.
Negotiate Always Sign.
Negotiate NTLM2 Key.
Supports 56-bit encryption.
Supports 128-bit encryption.
Client will provide master key in Type 3 Session Key field.
```

Works perfectly fine in .NET 4.5

How can I get that to work in 2.0?

How to remove **Seal (confidentiality)** if it makes problems?

How can I make the complete calls in 2.0 without using WebClient or HttpWebRequest ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, adding for future reference

```
CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(new Uri(url),
"NTLM",
new NetworkCredential(username.Split('\\')[1], password, username.Split('\\')[0]));
return cc;
```